# How to get bounding box for div element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to calculate bounding box for div element via jQuery/JavaScript.

I tried like this:

```
//Left side of box 
document.getElementById("myElement").offsetLeft; 
//Top side of box 
document.getElementById("myElement").offsetTop;  
//Right side of box
document.getElementById("myElement").offsetLeft + document.getElementById("myElement").offsetWidth; 
//Bottom side of box 
document.getElementById("myElement").offsetTop + document.getElementById("myElement").offsetHeight;
```

It returns some values. whether it is correct way to get bounding box for div element via jQuery / JavaScript.

I need something like `getBBox()` method in  `SVG` element. it will return `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` of an element. Sameway how can I get bounding box for div element?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can get the bounding box of any element by calling [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

```
var rect = document.getElementById("myElement").getBoundingClientRect();
```

That will return an object with left, top, width and height fields.

Comment: Be aware that `getBoundingClientRect` will return coordinates relative to the viewport, and not the document or parent.

Answer (score 129):

As this is specifically tagged for jQuery -

```
$("#myElement")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

or

```
$("#myElement").get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
```

(These are functionally identical, in some older browsers `.get()` was slightly faster)

Note that if you try to get the values via jQuery calls then it will not take into account any css transform values, which can give unexpected results...

Note 2: In jQuery 3.0 it has changed to using the proper `getBoundingClientRect()` calls for its own dimension calls (see the [jQuery Core 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-width-height-css-quot-width-quot-and-css-quot-height-quot-can-return-non-integer-values)) - which means that the other jQuery answers will finally always be correct - but only when using the new jQuery version - hence why it's called a breaking change...

Answer (score 19):

using jQuery:

```
myelement=$("#myelement")
[myelement.offset().left, myelement.offset().top,  myelement.width(), myelement.height()]
```

Comment: yes thanks i knew this concept. am asking about whether it is correct way to get bounding box of an element ?

Comment: I suggest using `outerWidth()` instead of just `width()`. So that, it will consider the padding value if any.

Comment: This doesn't take into account css transform - so doesn't give the correct answers if that's used. It could also be optmised by caching the `offset()` result.

Comment: what if the element has absolute position?